# PHP 8.0.12 upgrade to PHP 8.1 - multiple module errors

Tags: php, php-8.1

I've been making upgrades on my Dev workstation using XAMPP for a long time now, from the various version 7s up through 8.012.

I seem to have hit a wall upgrading to 8.1.

I've edited the apache config to use the new version of php. Taking the `php.ini-development` and renaming it to `php.ini`, then uncommenting the openssl extension has no effect after I restart apache:

```
extension=openssl
```

Openssl isn't enabled in the php info page:

[image]

And if I try and enable mongodb by moving my extension over from the previous installation, and uncomment the extension in `php.ini` and restarting apache again I get an error:

`extension=php_mongodb.dll`

[image]

Update: I now find that enabling ANY PHP module does not work under PHP 8.1.

I can roll back to the previous version of `php-8.0.12` and have a fully functioning php again. When I roll back to the previous version enabling and disabling PHP modules still works. It does not work under PHP 8.1.

I'd like to stay up to date with the latest release if at all possible!

What am I doing wrong with this version of PHP? Why can't I enable anything?

Comment: you seem to be using an extension that was compiled for 8.0 (as indicated by the dll path). You can't move an extension built using a different installation. You need to get one that was built for 8.1

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm not sure that's available yet for MongoDB. If I could install it by `pecl install mongodb` I would. But you have to enable `openssl` to do that. And 8.1 won't even allow me to enable `openssl` as I mention in the post.

Comment: In 8.0 for windows the line is `extension=php_openssl.dll` but you're mentioning `extension=openssl` are you sure that's correct? Not sure if this has changed in 8.1. Unfortunately I don't know how you can build extensions in windows. In Linux I have managed to build them from source before so there may be an equivalent guide if you can't find an 8.1 version for mongodb

Comment: Ok I've tried changing it to `extension=openssl.dll` and restarted apache again. No change! The openssl extension still doesn't show in `phpinfo`.

Comment: how about `php_openssl.dll` ? Basically available extensions should be in <your PHP installation path>\ext so check if it's in there at all

Comment: OK I've checked the ext directory in the php 8.1 folder and the `php_openssl.dll` file is there. I've used `extension=php_openssl.dll` in my `php.ini` for 8.1 and there's still no change after restarting apache! Openssl is still not enabled in the `phpinfo` page!

Comment: Where did you get XAMPP? If you only upgraded php to 8.1, extensions that are installed by XAMP won't work because they are from a different version. You have to build them from source codes yourself or wait for available dlls on the pecl site.

Comment: openssl is a builtin extension so it should work, try to run `php -r openssl_encrypt();` from the command line, then check the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had to set the FULL PATH to the extensions directory on Windows. Once I did that and restarted, I was able to enable / disable extensions. Look for this line in `php.ini` and adjust it to your needs:

```
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php-8.1.0\ext\"
```

This setting only seems important on Windows. Set that line the way you want it, restart apache and you should be good to go!

Comment: What should I do if it doesn't work and after I restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

You are copying an incompatible module compiled with the older version. If you are upgrading the PHP version, You'll need an extension DLL file compiled with that specific version of PHP and suitable for your server environment. You can download the compatible packages from here [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/). Download and put the .dll file in your extension directory. Then, you'll need to enable that extension.
Here is the guide for the windows system [Installing a PHP extension on Windows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php).

For MongoDB, get it here https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

Comment: The problem isn't just the MongoDB extension at this point. NONE of the modules I am trying to load work. See the update to my post!

Comment: This answer applies to all the .dll extensions. not limited to mongodb.

Comment: When you install PHP, it comes with a few preconfigured extensions. you need to download and set up an additional module with the same process mentioned in the answer according to your PHP version and system arch.